# how to show up the URL that I embedded to a html page?

Tags: url, hyperlink, show

I've written this to a html page and the output is like this

[image: the output is like this]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>
    <body>       
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:1200px;">
    <object type="text/html" data="http://www.live24sports.com"
            style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
    </object>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:1200px;">
    <object type="text/html" data="http://paste.hgcommunity.net"
            style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
    </object>
    </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to get `data` attribute. you can use the below method to get any attribute.

if you can use jquery

```
$('object').attr('data');
```

or with plain javascript

```
document.querySelector('object').getAttribute("data");
```

## edit

since you have multiple `object`s you can use

```
document.querySelectorAll('object')
```

to get a list of all objects and then use a loop to `getAttribute('data');` on each item.

Comment: thanks a lot for you reply. Can you please give me an example for this?

Comment: I actually want to show up the link bar; exactly like a tab in a browser.

Comment: can't understand what you are saying. please edit your question to make it clear

Comment: see the picture that I uploaded,
there are two websites loading on a signle page;
I can use each of the website dynamically without loading the full page/tab;
and I can also create backlink or something to that page or click a link on that page then it will move to another URL of that site;
Now how to get the new url that was moved to; 
or how show up the links on the output with each of the websites?